# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.getChildrem is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
getitem: function(){
    $this.users = $data.data;
    $this.users = $this.users.filter( function(item) {
    if(item.status === true ) { 
        if( item.children.length > 0 ){
            item.children = this.getChildrem(item.children, true);
        }
        return item;
    }}); 
},
getChildrem: function(node, estatus){
    $children = node.filter( function(item) {
    if(item.status === estatus ) {              
        if( item.children.length > 0 ){
            item.children = this.getChildrem(item.children, estatus);
        }
        return item;
    }});       
    return $children;    
},
```

this is a simple function recursive, I just get all items(parents and chlidren) with status 'true'but I'm having this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.getChildrem is not a function
```

Why I'm getting this error???

Comment: That's not the issue @luk2302 as it's used consistently for some reason.

Comment: what is the enclosing scope? If it is a method on an object, then you will have to replace the this with the object name.

Comment: typo?????????????

Comment: "childrem" isn't a word. @Jonhwick. It's "children".

Answer (score 1):

When you define the function that you pass into `node.filter`, the `this` context changes. You can avoid this by passing in an arrow function instead, or using `.bind`.

So instead of

```
getChildrem: function(node, estatus){
    $children = node.filter( function(item) {
```

try this:

```
getChildrem: function(node, estatus){
    $children = node.filter( (item) => {
```

Comment: I'm getting Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.getChildrem is not a function

Comment: set some breakpoints then @Jonhwick

Answer (score 0):

It's because the callback function is using the global scope, while that object is in a different scope

```js
var obj = {
  test(){
    (function(){console.log(this);})(); //Prints global object
    (()=>{console.log(this);})(); // prints local object
  }
}
```

You would need to change that normal function to an arrow function,because the arrow function will capture the enclosing scope